# MultiLabelBinarizer: inverse_transform fails on a single sample?

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I want to apply the `inverse_transform`of MultiLabelBinarizer to a single sample, e.g.:

```
labels = ['Architektur & Garten',
          'Ganzheitliches Bewusstsein',
          'Glaube & Ethik',
          'Kinderbuch & Jugendbuch',
          'Künste',
          'Literatur & Unterhaltung',
          'Ratgeber',
          'Sachbuch']

samples = []
for l in labels:
   samples.append([l])

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
m = MultiLabelBinarizer()
m.fit_transform(samples)
```

If I now apply the MultiLabelBinarizer to a matrix it works:

```
s = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
m.inverse_transform(s)
[('Ganzheitliches Bewusstsein',), ('Sachbuch',)]
```

If I however try to apply it to a single sample, i.e. a vector it fails:

```
import numpy as np
s = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
m.inverse_transform(s)

--> 957         if yt.shape[1] != len(self.classes_):
    958             raise ValueError('Expected indicator for {0} classes, but got {1}'
    959                              .format(len(self.classes_), yt.shape[1]))
```

Comment: looking through the source code it seems inverse_transform always expect a vector of two dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your comment it looks like you've solved it. In case this helps someone else, some more detail:

In the first example, if we print the dimensions of `s` we get `(2, 8)`:

```
>>> s = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
>>> s.shape
(2,8)
```

In the second example, if we do the same thing, we get `(8,)`:

```
>>> s = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> s.shape
(8,)
```

The issue is with the second example and the error `inverse_transform` throws is helpful by showing that it expects `yt.shape[1]` to be available. In the second example that dimension is not available, hence the error.

**This can be fixed two ways:**

1. Just add square brackets: `s = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` becomes `s = np.array(`**[**`[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`**]**`)`
2. Reshape: `s = np.reshape(s, (1, s.shape[0]))`

Either way, the output of `s.shape` after will be `(1, 8)` and `m.inverse_transform(s)` will work as expected.